# Removing the characters from a arraylist holding the alphabets based on the characters that appear in users input

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm doing a project were I need to remove letters systematically from an `ArrayList` as they show up in the words that the user puts in. Then all the remaining characters are displayed and then the elimination process continues until only vowels are left.

I can’t seem to get it to eliminate the characters without the program crashing.

Here's the problematic code:

```java
public static void Mapper(){
    Scanner make = new Scanner(System.in);

    char Aphabets[] ={'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};
    ArrayList<Character> Alpabets = new ArrayList<>();
    String word = make.nextLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < Aphabets.length; i++) {
        Alpabets. add(i,Aphabets[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        Alpabets.remove(word.charAt(i));
    }
    System.out.println(Alpabets);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean "remove **letters**"? --- Quoting Wikipedia: *"An **alphabet** is a standardized set of basic written symbols or graphemes (called letters)"*, e.g. `A` is a letter, and `R` is a letter. The whole set of 26 letters is (one example of) an alphabet.

Comment: yes that is what i mean

Comment: Then you should **edit** the question and clarify your meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Alpabets.remove(word.charAt(i));
```

to

```
Alpabets.remove((Object) word.charAt(i));
```

The issue is that `List.remove` has two implementations (it's an overloaded method):

- One implementation that takes an index as argument: [`List.remove(int index)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-int-) ("remove the 5th element from the list")
- One that removes an actual object from the list [`List.remove(Object o)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-java.lang.Object-) ("remove the number 5 from the list).

By calling using `Alpabets.remove(word.charAt(i));` you're accidentally invoking the one that takes an index, and if you give it a "large enough" character (characters can be seen as numerical values in Java), you'll hit an index out of bounds in the remove method.

By casting the argument to `Object`, you force the correct method to be called.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can also use mapping a key and a value and remove based on user input.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.